# Mapping complex objects using Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

```
public class ProductEntity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public CategoryEntity Category {get; set;}   
}

public class CategoryEntity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public CategoryDTO Category {get; set;}   
}

public class CategoryDTO
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}


public class CategoryProfile : Profile
{
    public CategoryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CategoryEntity, CategoryDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class ProductProfile: Profile
{
    public ProductProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}E
```

Hey guys, I'm a beginner developer, and I would like some help in this example it is possible to reuse the CategoryProfile mepement in the ProductProfile, my code always returns as empty, I would not like to include the "CreateMap<CategoryEntity, CategoryDTO>().ReverseMap();" in ProductProfile.

I'm using dotnet Core 6.

I included CreateMap<CategoryEntity, CategoryDTO>() and it worked, but I would like to do this in a way that it was possible to reuse the logic applied in the profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can add both profiles to `AutoMapper` by calling the `AddProfiles` method on the `MapperConfiguration` instance.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new ProductProfile());
    cfg.AddProfile(new CategoryProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

By adding both profiles to the same configuration, `AutoMapper` will be able to use the mapping configurations defined in both profiles when mapping objects between types.

Profiles can be added to the main mapper configuration in a number of ways, either directly or by [automatically scanning for profiles](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration):

```
// Scan for all profiles in an assembly
// ... using instance approach:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddMaps(myAssembly);
});
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(myAssembly));

// Can also use assembly names:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        "Foo.UI",
        "Foo.Core"
    });
);

// Or marker types for assemblies:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        typeof(HomeController),
        typeof(Entity)
    });
);
```

Comment: Or simply use the DI package that does that.